# Saving PayPal email address in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob, paypal

Using CartThrob and PayPal Express, is it possible to save the PayPal email address that is used when an order is placed?

At the moment, I'm only saving the first name, last name, and email address that is entered on the checkout page of the website, but this email address may be different to the PayPal email address.

The only info that is currently being returned from PayPal is the transaction ID and error message, so just wondering if and how we can save the PayPal email address too, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would have to customise the paypal express payment file to do the following and then modify it to capture the e-mail IF given back.

```
Obtaining Buyer Consent to Receive Promotional Email
You can obtain the buyer’s consent to receive email promotions on PayPal pages. PayPal returns the email address in the response to GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

NOTE:Obtaining buyer consent to receive promotional email is available with API Version 61.0 or later.
To obtain the buyer’s email address, set the BUYEREMAILOPTINENABLE field to 1 in the call to SetExpressCheckout.

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing
```